# Need help tweaking c# multi-threaded routine

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've created a windows service which runs a multi-threaded routine on a machine with 24 cores, 48 virtual, using `Parallel.ForEach`. This service, which has been running great in a production environment, bulk copies data into an SQL Server database. Currently it does this very well, around 6000 inserts per second, but I believe it can be tweaked. Below is part of the code I am using; there's an example of current functionality and proposed changes for tweaking. As can be seen from the code, currently a lock is taken for every call to Add, which I believe makes the `Parallel.ForEach` somewhat non-parallel. So I'm looking for a "fix"; and hoping my new method, also defined in the code, would do the trick.

```
    public class MainLoop
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
            var options = new ParallelOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount * 2
            };

            var workQueueManager = new ObjWorkQueueManager(queueSize: 1000);

            // ignore the fact that this while loop would be a never ending loop,
            // there's other logic not shown here that exits the loop!
            while (true)
            {
                ICollection<object> work = GetWork();

                Parallel.ForEach(work, options, (item) =>
                {
                    workQueueManager.AddOLD(item);
                });
            }
        }

        private ICollection<object> GetWork()
        {
            // return list of work from some arbitrary source
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class ObjWorkQueueManager
    {
        private readonly int _queueSize;
        private ObjDataReader _queueDataHandler;
        private readonly object _sync;

        public ObjWorkQueueManager(int queueSize) 
        {
            _queueSize = queueSize;
            _queueDataHandler = new ObjDataReader(queueSize);
            _sync = new object();
        }

        // current Add method works great, but blocks with EVERY call
        public void AddOLD(object value)
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                if (_queueDataHandler.Add(value) == _queueSize)
                {
                    // create a new thread to handle copying the queued data to repository
                    Thread t = new Thread(SaveQueuedData);
                    t.Start(_queueDataHandler);

                    // start a new queue 
                    _queueDataHandler = new ObjDataReader(_queueSize);
                }
            }
        }

        // hoping for a new Add method to work better by blocking only 
        // every nth call where n = _queueSize
        public void AddNEW(object value)
        {
            int queued;
            if ((queued = _queueDataHandler.Add(value)) >= _queueSize)
            {
                lock (_sync)
                {
                    if (queued == _queueSize)
                    {
                        Thread t = new Thread(SaveQueuedData);
                        t.Start(_queueDataHandler);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (queued == 0)
            {
                lock (_sync)
                {
                    _queueDataHandler = new ObjDataReader(_queueSize);

                    AddNEW(value);
                }
            }
        }

        // this method will Bulk Copy data into an SQL DB
        private void SaveQueuedData(object o)
        {
            // do something with o as ObjDataReader
        }
    }

    // implements IDataReader, Read method of IDataReader dequeues from _innerQueue
    public class ObjDataReader
    {
        private readonly int _capacity;
        private Queue<object> _innerQueue;

        public ObjDataReader(int capacity)
        {
            _capacity = capacity;
            _innerQueue = new Queue<object>(capacity);
        }

        public int Add(object value)
        {
            if (_innerQueue.Count < _capacity)
            {
                _innerQueue.Enqueue(value);
                return _innerQueue.Count;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you use to establish SQL connection? If you used EF Core, you would be able to avoid that lock altogether and just perform a bulk copy. All you would need to ensure is for each ask to have their own DbContext. But I assume any other method of establishing an SQL connection would also do, as long as the same connection is not shared between different tasks.

Comment: I agree with Dejan; unless the other code not shown is doing further work using the newly inserted PKs I don't see any possible contention. I'm curious whether you first tried using simple async Tasks before rolling your own task pool, and if so, what about them didn't work for you?

Comment: Aside from the earlier comments, and as a note: you can avoid locking when using a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` in `ObjDataReader` instead of a `Queue<T>`. Your `Parallel.ForEach` is not much worth right now as you've already imagined. [Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Based on the fact that your comments refer to an IDataReader, I am going to assume you are using SqlBulkCopy.  I'd be curious to know what your use case is.  Are you expecting GetWork to return very small amounts of work that you are attempting to batch, or is GetWork returning very large amounts of work (per call) that you are attempting to break up?  Or both?

Comment: Not using EF; written my own data layer, I use System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader).

Comment: I considered using a ConcurrentQueue, but wouldn't that also potentially block every call as well? Doesn't ConcurrentQueue use it's own internal locking mechanism?

Comment: Robert, yes, I am using SqlBulkCopy, GetWork can return any number of items, from 1 to 10,000. And yes, this is about BOTH batching and breaking up, as necessary.

Comment: I would be surprised if implementing two threads wasn't more efficient -- one for the producer (calling GetWork, and stuffing into ConcurrentQueue<T>), and second calling TryDequeue into a list until either you reached your batch size or until it returned false, and then call the bulk insert on that same thread.  If you TryDequeue returned false, and you haven't copied anything yet, then just go to sleep for a short bit -- 100ms or so.

Comment: And I suggest this because really Sql Server usually (but not always... hardware, partitioning, and workload dependent) doesn't significantly process multiple bulk copies any faster than single threading them.